# MS BI Dev studio 2008 - table name and data based on query

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Hi Experts :)
Im using MS BI development studio 2008.
I have a dataset with about 12 fields, one of them is "region". My aim is to display tables with all the fields sorted by region, but each region should be in separate table. The table should be named after region. When there is no data for specific region there should be no table displayed.
I am quite new in MS reporting, I did it in Cognos with sorting and groupping but this principle seems not to work here. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

OK guys,
so you need to use List and set groupping on list by expression.